How to fix Facebook SDK for new release on Android
I'm trying to upload my Unity project to the google play console but I get the following message when uploading the .aab:
"Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider533108020750447, com.mustansarali.MyApp.FacebookInitProvider."
Since my app was passed to me by another developer I suppose I have to change something with the Facebook SDK, but I don't know what specifically or how to.
I tried looking in here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/, but it got into modifying internal files pretty quickly so I wanted to ask for guidance here.

The help page you have linked clear states that the number in ContentProvider533108020750447 is the Facebook "AppId". Therefore it seems like you need a new AppId https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#app-id
